# Create form dynamically using javascript JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I have this JSON object that I am trying to create an html form based on its properties. How would I go about targeting multiple level to create the various fields, but then target deeper to get the details about the field. I am not set on this format either.

```
{
    "Controls": [{
        "Button":{
            "Name":{
                "ID":"Name",
                "FieldType":"Input"
            },
            "x":{
                "ID":"X",
                "FieldType":"Input"
            },
            "y":{
                "ID":"Y",
                "FieldType":"Input"
            },
            "width":{
                "ID":"Width",
                "FieldType":"Input"
            },
            "height":{
                "ID":"Height",
                "FieldType":"Input"
            },
            "Action":{
                "ID":"Action",
                "FieldType":"DropDown"
            }
        },

    }]
}
```

In the above example, all the fields except for 'Action' would be inputs and 'Action would be a Dropdown.

Comment: but Rob...why are most of the fields children of `Button`. Not clear how a dropdown would relate to a button

Comment: I think you should maybe make this a little less redundant? The ID field has the same name as the key, which you'd already know when you access the object anyway.

Comment: @charlietfl Basically the children of Button are specifying what "About the button" can be modified. For example a Button has a Action. I want a Dropdown to give the user a choice for the Action assigned to the Button. Make sense?

Comment: @Mutahhir Yes, that would be OK to. I put it in there to stay consistant and organized. Im open though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to look into [jquery.dform](https://github.com/daffl/jquery.dform) plugin that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Looks promising. I will check it out! Thank you

Comment: This Rocks! Problem solved..